# Which query reproduces \dconfig+ command output in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Which query reproduce the exact output of `\dconfig+`? (List of non-default configuration parameters)

I've tried

```
SELECT name, setting, source, sourcefile,pending_restart 
FROM pg_settings WHERE source !='default';
```

But the output is different and `\dconfig+` is more accurated. I'd like the same output of `\dconfig+` using SQL